# Multiply Two Matrices in R

Tags: r, matrix

```
structure(c(-13.2728762809309, 1.4589335335744, 0.484047921906014, 
0.961191008159664, 9.8283305061549, 0.719751064235688, -12.9935586779498, 
1.54850677442014, -13.1416306849761, 1.45529160258359), .Dim = c(2L, 
5L), .Dimnames = list(c("(Intercept)", "PJMPWr[, x]"), NULL))
```

Need to forecast using these coefficients and create a new matrix using, e.g. c(20,30,40) such that it equals to -13.2728*20 +1.4589,-13.2728*30 +1.4589,-13.2728*40 +1.4589..

Comment: This is a bit unclear.  Your title says "multiply two matrices", but you've listed one as a vector `c(20,30,40)`.  I guess your intent is to convert this to a `3x2` matrix (by adding a column of ones for the intercept), so you can multiply it by your `2x5` matrix?  Also, the row you've named `(Intercept)` is not the one being used as the intercept in the formula you give at the end -- are the row names reversed?

Comment: yes..eventually to get a 3 by 5 matrix, where multiple each number in c(20,30,40)  by  PJMPWr and add the Intercept.

Answer (score 2):

One way you could do it is like this:

```
(mat <- structure(c(-13.2728762809309, 1.4589335335744, 0.484047921906014, 0.961191008159664, 9.8283305061549,
                    0.719751064235688, -12.9935586779498, 1.54850677442014, -13.1416306849761, 1.45529160258359),
                  .Dim = c(2L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(c("(Intercept)", "PJMPWr[, x]"), NULL)))
#                   [,1]      [,2]      [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
# (Intercept) -13.272876 0.4840479 9.8283305 -12.993559 -13.141631
# PJMPWr[, x]   1.458934 0.9611910 0.7197511   1.548507   1.455292

(vec <- c(20, 30, 40))
# [1] 20 30 40

t(mat[2,] %*% t(vec) + mat[1,])
#          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
# [1,] 15.90579 19.70787 24.22335 17.97658 15.96420
# [2,] 30.49513 29.31978 31.42086 33.46164 30.51712
# [3,] 45.08447 38.93169 38.61837 48.94671 45.07003
```

---

**Some Explanation:**

1. Since `mat[1,]` and `mat[2,]` are single rows, the default behavior is that they're coerced to 1-dimensional vectors. (See `` help(`[`) ``.)
2. `t(vec)` converts the vector `vec` to a `1 x 3` matrix (See `help(t)`.)
3. In the matrix multiplication `mat[2,] %*% t(vec)`, the vector `mat[2,]` is treated as a `5 x 1` matrix to make the two arguments conformable. (See `` help(`%*%`) ``.)  Thus, the result of the multiplication is a `5 x 3` matrix.
4. When adding the vector `mat[1,]` to the `5 x 3` matrix, the elements of the vector are recycled along the columns of the matrix.
5. Finally, the result is transposed to convert it to the desired `3 x 5` matrix.

Comment: Based on the row name, I assume you want the first row of your matrix to be the intercept, so you end up with `1.4589*20 - 13.2728`, etc. (rather than `-13.2728*20 +1.4589` as you wrote).  But if I assumed wrong, just swap `mat[1,]` and `mat[2,]`

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following with `mapply`:

```
mapply(function(x, y) x[2] * y + x[1],
       #your coefficients
       as.data.frame(mat),
       #your vector replicated 5 times
       replicate(5, c(20, 30, 40), simplify = FALSE))

#           V1       V2       V3       V4       V5
#[1,] 15.90579 19.70787 24.22335 17.97658 15.96420
#[2,] 30.49513 29.31978 31.42086 33.46164 30.51712
#[3,] 45.08447 38.93169 38.61837 48.94671 45.07003
```